# How to stop signal propagation from master process to children?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell

I'm running an app using `cluster`.
I need to find a memory leak in the master process, so I send  a signal to the master `kill -SIGUSR1 424242`. It enables *inspector mode* on this process and I can use **Chrome Dev Tools** (chrome://inspect/#devices) to investigate my problem.

Everything works, but the the problem is that the same signal is propagated down to the child processes. Upon receiving the signal they try to enable *inspector mode* and fail, because the port is already used by the master process. They log some errors and that's it. No big deal.  But I'm wondering is there a way to stop signal propagation from master to children?

Comment: You don't want to do this. The way to do this is to remove the child process from the parent's process group but this makes the child a daemon and will cause the child to continue executing when you stop the parent. Just live with the minor inconvenience.

Comment: @slebetman, hey, thank you! I guess I'll just have to ignore. Have a nice day, good sir!